# Java: Turning user input into an array and reading from that array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to have a user input a list of numbers and store it as an array, then find the median of that array. When I try to get the user input into an array, I keep getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:9)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[9];
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
         userValues[i] = sc.nextInt();
      }
}
}
```

I am eventually trying to find the median of that Array.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code, perhaps the inputs are wrong? Are you inputting empty Strings? E.g. only pressing Enter?

Comment: I am using the normal eclipse IDE and I am using the inputs of 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I am not using the normal eclipse IDE actually, this is on zybooks so it has its own interpreter I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears in the following cases:

1 - using [Online IDEs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) like the linked one.
2 - Not adding console to your solution when launching it via Eclipse.
3 - Having strange input containing end of input like ^D (Linux) or ^Z (Windows)

The solution - use proper IDE, check your startup configuration or remove the end of file symbols in your input(I gues that you might be copying the faulty symbol from somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I think your input is wrong. You're calling `sc.nextInt()` 9 times but according to your comment on one of the answers, only providing inputs of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - so on the 6th try you're hitting Enter or doing something else to terminate input, and `nextInt()` is expecting 9 integers. You need to either use a different `Scanner` method and validate the input or provide 9 integers every time.